# How to regenerate the voterlist

Tags: staking, migration, pallet-staking

Since I have an issue with the voterlist in a solo chain, what would be the correct way to trigger `unsafe_regenerate` from the bagslist pallet instance in the staking pallet ?

https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/src/pallet_bags_list/lib.rs.html#341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper way to call this method is writing a storage migration similar to [this one](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/staking/src/migrations.rs#L385).

Keep in mind, that using `enum` for storage versioning is not the best approach, so I would instead use integers, similar to [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/fast-unstake/src/migrations.rs). [Here's](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/commit/b85f85e08dafa2935dc20d1b13af2ca36ba3ea64#diff-103bae13a15813f338cb0bb67e77f3687c2c811fe75b2defd1cdc3d2afd6aa17R107-R111) how StorageVersion is defined for a pallet.

Alternatively, you can just implement the migration within your runtime, without `StorageVersion` checks, but then you need to make sure to remove it before your next runtime upgrade, otherwise it will be executed again.
An example of this is available [here](https://github.com/hicommonwealth/edgeware-node/blob/7b66f4f0a9ec184fdebcccd41533acc728ebe9dc/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L845-L866).

[Here's](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/6253/files#diff-e5e76e02c0d16e79c70b024cbe3c6ea56f3249382a0f987ba203c34fcb40ed66R1600) an example of adding a migration to the runtime.

If you want to check the assumptions about your migration - use [`try-runtime`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/try_runtime_cli/index.html) to test it against your current network state. That will reveal any potential errors and also give you an idea about consumed weight.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer. I'll definitely apply all of that.